# Get element by classname from one component for use in another component using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components, elementref

I have a background image on a component however in another component when an item is clicked, I would like for the background image in the other component to shrink. The component is current not being picked up

**Bg.html** (The component with the background I'd like to shorten)

```
 <section ngClass="main-bg">
  </section>
```

**box.component.ts** (The component where I'd like to shorten the bg)

```
  export class BoxComponent implements OnInit {
     
    main: any;

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.main = (this.ElByClassName.nativeElement).querySelector('.main-bg');
  }




    ShortedBg()
    {
      if (this.main != null) {
          this.main.style.height = "31vh";
          console.log("section picked up");
        }
        else {
          console.log("section not picked up");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try enclosing inside square brackets, like `[ngClass]`

Comment: Still does not get picked up

Comment: Try this `[ngClass]="'main-bg'"`

Comment: Also from what I see you've used class to select the DOM element. But instead, why don't you try having a conditional class and having different CSS properties for each class. In this way, you could have easily handle the appearance instead of a dedicated function